# Генерация форм пользователем на JavaScript, jQuery, php?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день. Поставлена задача:
Некий сервис, в котором пользователь, авторизовавшись, может создать собственный опросный лист. Пользователь может указать любое количество вопросов и выбрать варианты ответов (всего их два: "радио да/нет" и поле для ввода). Данная форма записывается в базу, откуда может быть выведена на определенной странице, а также самим же пользователем для редактирования. Встречал ли кто-нибудь подобные скрипты?
Из моих идей 
1) реализовать добавление вопросов с помощью append(), потом чистый html код записывается в базу в одно поле таблицы. все хорошо, но не понятно, как реализовать редактирование (уменьшить-увеличить количество вопросов, изменить вариант ответа на них)?
2) В базе создать большое количество полей для каждого вопроса, и при выводе формы не показывать пустые. (этот метод мне кажется не очень удобным).
Спасибо тем, кто поможет подобными скриптами, или идеями в написании

Answer (score 5):

Это называется генератор форм. Сам писал такие несколько штук, из чего сделал вывод, что всякий генератор форм - это бардак и куча мусора в проекте. На каждую форму не угодишь.

Другое дело, когда есть строгий шаблон для формы. Хотя и тут возможно увеличение требований с течением времени.

```
Как пример:
Таблица для типов Полей (text, radio, select...) тэги, описание...
Таблица для Полей формы (id формы, id поля, 'label', тип поля ...)
Таблица для Форм (id формы, заголовок, другие параметры ...)
```

Comment: спасибо, подумаю над таким вариантом. Репутации не хватает, плюсик нажать не могу

Comment: Кстати, можно сгенерированный html формы хранить в БД. Это значительно упростит вывод страницы.

Comment: да, как раз предположил это в своих идеях. Но тогда возникают проблемы с редактированием - только если создавать новую форму

Comment: еще приходили идеи хранить форму в сериализованном массиве

Comment: Совместите два метода. Для редактирования используйте структуры хранящиеся в БД. В таблицу для форм добавьте поле (`content` - TEXT), куда сохраняется сгенерированный после редактирования формы HTML код.

Comment: Большое спасибо, хорошая идея)